# How to fix black screen on Android emulator when opening game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

When I build my unity game for an android emulator, soon as the game starts the screen goes black.

Already tried changing the graphic settings and also running without docker running and running in cold or quick boot

This is the error I'm getting:

````
2019-04-01 22:20:27.148 3373-3393/com.Yeoldegames.Flappybirdcyborg E/EGL_emulation: tid 3393: eglGetConfigAttrib(868): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2019-04-01 22:20:35.540 3373-3373/com.Yeoldegames.Flappybirdcyborg E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/natives_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/natives_blob_64.bin
2019-04-01 22:20:35.540 3373-3373/com.Yeoldegames.Flappybirdcyborg E/ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin: java.io.FileNotFoundException: assets/snapshot_blob_64.bin
2019-04-01 22:20:36.024 3373-3393/com.Yeoldegames.Flappybirdcyborg E/Ads: Google Mobile Ads SDK initialization functionality unavailable for this session. Ad requests can be made at any time.```
````

Comment: It seems to be missing assets..

Comment: It seems the problem is with Google Mobile Ads plugin in your project, you can delete it and try again.

Comment: Thanks guys, I believe something is wrong with the emulator. Removed the plugin for now, didn't get it to work!